# Best way to copy a vtbl into a theoretically compatible structure of function pointers in GCC 32bits on a harvard arch ESP32

Tags: c++, function, pointers, esp32, vtable

I'm writing some system code for a filesystem driver for an ESP32 based IoT gadget. My toolchain will always be gcc because the ESP32's developer framework requires GCC. The architecture is a known quantity. Portability is no concern. Function pointers are the same size as other function pointers and data pointers.

I've got a (googlable) struct called esp_vfs_t which somewhat simplified, looks like this

```
typedef struct
{
    int flags;      /*!< ESP_VFS_FLAG_CONTEXT_PTR or ESP_VFS_FLAG_DEFAULT */
    union {
        ssize_t (*write_p)(void* p, int fd, const void * data, size_t size);                         /*!< Write with context pointer */
        ssize_t (*write)(int fd, const void * data, size_t size);                                    /*!< Write without context pointer */
    };
    union {
        off_t (*lseek_p)(void* p, int fd, off_t size, int mode);                                     /*!< Seek with context pointer */
        off_t (*lseek)(int fd, off_t size, int mode);                                                /*!< Seek without context pointer */
    };
    union {
        ssize_t (*read_p)(void* ctx, int fd, void * dst, size_t size);                               /*!< Read with context pointer */
        ssize_t (*read)(int fd, void * dst, size_t size);                                            /*!< Read without context pointer */
    };
    ...
} ...
```

You can see that each function pointer is a union, but I'm only interested in the functions that take void* as their first argument.

Basically I want to OO this by creating a pure abstract class you can derive from, and because I want zero additional overhead for this feature, I want to copy the vtbl directly into this esp_vfs_t structure such that each function pointer is filled with the corresponding function pointer in my vtbl.

The code that I have to do it is ugly, but not crashing. It's simply not calling my functions for reasons I haven't determined yet.

I'm trying to assert that my function pointers got copied where I expect, but C++ won't let me compare addresses i need to compare in order to make it work. This is because the first argument for each function in the structure is void*, while of course the first argument to my vtbl functions are the class instance ptr itself.

The following code compiles and runs "successfully" if i remove the code to attempt to do that assert, but for whatever reason my functions aren't getting called (could be an unrelated issue)

What I expect is a crash or my functions to be called.
Ideally what I'd like for now is to get the code below that asserts to compile:

```
static bool mount(const char* mount_point,vfs_driver* driver) {
    if(nullptr==mount_point || nullptr==driver) {
        m_last_error=ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
        return false;
    }
    esp_vfs_t vfs;
    memset(&vfs,0,sizeof(vfs));
    vfs.flags = ESP_VFS_FLAG_CONTEXT_PTR;
    // try to assert these values
    void* test1;
    void* test2;
    memcpy(&test1,vfs.fstat,sizeof(void*));
    memcpy(&test2,&esp32::vfs_driver::fstat,sizeof(void*));
    memcpy(&vfs.write_p,driver,sizeof(vfs_driver));
    assert(test1==test2);
    // the above won't compile
    esp_err_t res = esp_vfs_register(mount_point,&vfs,driver);
    if(ESP_OK!=res) {
        m_last_error = res;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's the first bit of the abstract base class I've created

```
class vfs_driver {
public:
    virtual ssize_t write(int fd, const void * data, size_t size)=0;
    virtual off_t lseek(int fd, off_t size, int mode)=0;
    virtual ssize_t read(int fd, void * dst, size_t size)=0;
    virtual ssize_t pread(int fd, void *dst, size_t size, off_t offset)=0;
    virtual ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *src, size_t size, off_t offset)=0;
    virtual int open(const char * path, int flags, int mode)=0;
    virtual int close(int fd)=0;
    virtual int fstat(int fd, struct stat * st)=0;
    virtual int fsync(int fd)=0;
...
```

Comment: You realize that since `test1, test2` are uninitialized, you are memcpy'ing to a random place in memory?  That's not good, not even for testing purposes.

Comment: Can you state the precise error you get?  I would test it myself, but your code is incomplete... a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Whoops! thanks for catching that. I'll fix it

Comment: That's what  I want. I need to know the fn ptr address are the same. the fn ptr addresses are the data. I've updated the code in response to these comments. I got an error about casting the pointer to a bound function in C++, so I have updated the code to get to it by way of a static reference. It still errors with error: cannot convert 'int (esp32::vfs_driver::*)(int, stat*)' to 'const void*' when I try to memcpy it

Comment: Minimal reproducable is still quite a bit of code but i can check it into a github repo and link to it. You'll need the ESP-IDF installed, and the toolchain to actually build it